# In Android Studio MainActivity4 wont open

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio

I am new to programming so please help. I am practicing value transfer in Activities. When I put name and click Continue it does not open MainActivity4. I tried to look up but as I said I am so new I don't even know how to search this. There is no error message. It just restarts app or if I dont put any value in PersonName it just crashes. Please help :D

```js
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    String userName;
    //String userAge;
    EditText PersonName;
    //EditText PersonAge;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        PersonName =findViewById(R.id.PersonName);
        //PersonAge =findViewById(R.id.PersonAge);
        userName="";
        //userAge="";



    }

    public void Continue(View view){
        userName=PersonName.getText().toString();
        //userAge=PersonAge.getText().toString();
        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity4.class);
        intent.putExtra("userInput",userName);
       // intent.putExtra("userInputAge",userAge);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
}
```

```html
package com.talhakotenapps.word_based_rpg;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity4 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
        textView2=findViewById(R.id.PersonName);
        Intent  intent=getIntent();
        String userName=intent.getStringExtra("userInput");
        textView2.setText(userName);
    }
    public void Back(View view){
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Here is XML files of MainActivity4!

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity4">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Back"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="198dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onCreate` of your *MainActivity4.java* file, you're doing the following line:

```java
textView2 = findViewById(R.id.PersonName);
```

but if we look at the XML file of your activity, there's no View with id `PersonName`.

Maybe you were referring to `textView2`?

```java
textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```